# Vary SetInterval time

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to vary the time of the setInterval function, by selecting a different value of an array.

Why does the console log output return one index repeated, or nothing at all?

```
$("input.btn1").click(function() {
    var i = 0;
    //var timeOut = 1000;

    var timer = setInterval(function() {

/*  
    var timeArr = [
        1000,2000,3000
    ];
    var randInt = getRandomInt(0, 2);
    var timeOut = timeArr[randInt]; 
*/      


    if( i < btn2.length) {
             console.log("current timeout: " +timeOut);
         } else {
             clearInterval(timer);
            }
            i = i + 1;
        }, randTimeout());

}); 


function randTimeout() {
    var timeArr = [
        1000,2000,3000
    ];
    var randInt = getRandomInt(0, 2);
    var timeOut = timeArr[randInt]; 

    return timeOut;
}

function getRandomInt(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}
```

Comment: Think you're going to need to show us the code for `getRandomInt` to answer this...

Comment: The code shown can't work at all, because the `console.log()` is trying to use a `timeOut` variable that is commented out, and `btn2` is not defined. Please [edit] your question to provide a [minimal, *complete*, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: added to the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It happens because you call `randTimeout()` only once. It is not being calculated every time. Your code is similar to:

```
var timeout = randTimeout();
setInterval(function() {
  // ...
}, timeout);
```

If you want your interval to be executed at random intervals from the given array, you can utilize `setTimeout`:

```js
var timer, prevDate = new Date(), hitsLeft = 10;

function getRandomInt(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

function randTimeout() {
  var timeArr = [100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600];
  var randInt = getRandomInt(0, timeArr.length);
  var timeOut = timeArr[randInt];

  return timeOut;
}

function tick() {
  if (hitsLeft === 0) {
    console.log("Complete.");
    timer = null;
    return;
  }
  
  // Do whatever you need here. I just measure the passed time for demo
  var currDate = new Date();
  console.log("Passed time: " + (currDate - prevDate) + " ms (" + hitsLeft + " hits left)");
  prevDate = currDate; 

  // Here, you call tick() again, with random timeout
  hitsLeft--;
  timer = setTimeout(tick, randTimeout());
}

tick();
```